Starting autotrader bots on forex metatrader 4
I'm having trouble getting my bots to begin autotrading. I enable autotrading but nothing starts. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I have worked with my metatrader broker but they were unable to see what's wrong and the software developers won't be back till Monday.
